# L4&L5 positions?

Tags: distances, lagrange-point

I know that, in L4&L5, the distances to the two main bodies should be equal. Still, how can I calculate that distance with accuracy? How can I know that that distance is inside the equipotential surface?
Let's take, as an example, the Sun-Earth system and the Earth-Moon system.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distances to the two main bodies are not only equal, they are equal to the distance between the two main bodies. In other words, the two main bodies and L4 (or L5) form an equilateral triangle.